# Stochastic Process Moment Problems

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, moment-problem

Given a stochastic process $X:S\times \Omega\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ with $S\subset \Bbb{R}^d$, one can define its moment functions as follows (when they exist):

$$
M_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}(t_1,\ldots,t_n) = \Bbb{E}[X(t_1)^{\alpha_1}\cdots X(t_n)^{\alpha_n}] ,\quad t_1,\ldots,t_n\in S
$$  If one knows the first and second order moments, $\mu(t)$ and $c(t_1,t_2)$, there exists a process with these moments, in particular a Gaussian process.  What if I know higher order moments?  Is there a standard construction that produces a process $X$ with a given moment function sequence?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation. Do you mean $S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $x_i=X(i,\cdot)$? Or possibly $S\subset\mathbb R$ is arbitrary, and for any $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in S$ we have $M_\alpha(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\mathbb E[X(x_1)^{\alpha_1}\cdots X(x_n)^{\alpha_n}]$?

Comment: Right, sorry - confusing notation.  I'll edit the question.